# Simple question about custom method in RequestFactory

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I have RequestFactory with some request interface

```
public interface FooRequest extends RequestContext {
   Request<List<Foo>> findSmt();
}
```

I can't figure out where I should place `findSmt()` implementation and how I should do wiring with that implementation.

Comment: + I do not want use any static methods in my domain entities.

Comment: Why not create a class that **inherits** the interface `FooRequest`?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman - How I should make binding between `FooRequest` and `FooRequestImpl`?

Comment: You should not create a class that inherits the interface.  RequestFactory uses magic sauce to connect the classes that is outside the Java language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @Service annotation to denote a class that implements findSmt.  You should *not* inherit FooRequest.

```
@Service(FooRequestImpl.class)
public interface FooRequest extends RequestContext {
   Request<List<FooProxy>> findSmt();
}

...

public class FooRequestImpl
{
    List<FooDAO> findSmt()  //note that we dropped the Request and changed the Proxy to the DAO
    {
        return getFoos();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately in same cases I have been forced to put static methods in my domain entities.  I think it is not possible to create an `InstanceRequest` in a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

For Binding of the `findSmt()`, the [documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) on GWT-RPC states.

> The RequestFactory service stubs must
>   extend RequestContext and use the
>   @Service annotation to name the
>   associated service implementation
>   class on the server. The methods in a
>   service stub do not return entities
>   directly, but rather return subclasses
>   of
>   com.google.gwt.requestfactory.shared.Request.
>   This allows the methods on the
>   interface to be invoked asynchronously
>   with Request.fire() similar to passing
>   an AsyncCallback object to each
>   service method in GWT-RPC.

Example:

```
@Service(Foo.class)
public interface FooRequest extends RequestContext {
   Request<List<Foo>> findSmt();
}

public interface FooRequestFactory extends RequestFactory {

    FooRequest fooRequest();
}
```

Finally, wiring

```
final EventBus eventBus = new SimpleEventBus();
requestFactory = GWT.create(FooRequestFactory.class);
requestFactory.initialize(eventBus);
FooRequest request = requestFactory.fooRequest();
request.findSmt().fire(new Receiver() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(void arg0) {
    //My implementation comes here....  

    }
});
```

The `fire()` is where you wire your `findSmt()`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I used other method (by @Riley). But this seems interesting too. Unfortunately, I can't see where you put `findSmt()` implementation.

Comment: @Stas Kurilin, the implementation is done on `request.findSmt().fire()` method.

Comment: The `onSuccess` method is where the results of findSmt are sent on the client, not where findSmt is implemented.  I think you need to implement findSmt on the server in the class specified by the `@Service` annotation.  findSmt cannot be implemented on the client.